# Edit git remote log history

Tags: git, rebase

I did several git reverts and pushed to remote branch(meaning revert a commit and then revert revert...), which looks pretty annoying. I want to clean my local and remote log history to get rid of these revert logs. For example, when I want to keep the commits but remove log history for the last 4 revert commits, would it work to do git rebase -i HEAD~4 and selected fixup/squash for my local? If yes, would it work to then run git push -force so that the log history in remote syncs with my local and thus gets the last 4 log message cleaned?

Comment: Note that you should not do this kind of stuff if multiple people work on this repository.

Comment: They can always use git fetch and then git reset --hard origin/master? is it correct?

Comment: You can do whatever you like by pushing with force. Whether you _should_ is a matter of opinion.

Comment: @user3388437 "*They can always use git fetch and then git reset --hard origin/master?*" Not if they have local not yet pushed commits. As a member of a team you're very much discouraged to perform forced pushes. My advice is: please refrain.

Comment: The thing is that _if people that understand git details are involved_, it is not much of a problem to force-push and rewrite history of a branch, as long as the developers are in sync... but the level of the question makes it apparent that command of the tool/concepts is still not there (not saying it is bad.... just in the making). So refraining from force-pushing is the right course of action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Reset last 4 commits `git reset HEAD~4`
2. Saving your changes `git stash`
3. Overwrite remote commit history `git push --force-with-lease`
4. Apply stashed changes `git stash pop`
5. Create a single commit `git add --all & git commit`

**Make sure your changes are not going to affect others!!!**